# JayData oData request with custom headers

Tags: wcf, http-headers, wcf-data-services, jaydata, datajs

I need to send custom headers to my wcf oData Service but with the following function the headers dont get modified.

```
entities.onReady(function () {

    entities.prepareRequest = function(r) {
        r[0].headers['APIKey'] = 'ABC';
    };

    entities.DataServiceClient.toArray(function (cli) {
        cli.forEach(function (c) {
            console.log(c.Name)
        });
    });
});
```

headers are not affected. any clue?

thanks!

Comment: just a quick check: is DataServiceClient an EntitySet? Could you show your request headers and context definition? This is working for me

Comment: @Robesz Yes it is a an EntitySet, I have answered my post bellow. let me know if you have any other way! what version of JayData and dataJS are you using?

Comment: I'M using JayData 1.3.2 and datajs 1.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

On second thought, it seems like there is still something broken in JayData for MERGE requests.

This is NOT CORS and has nothing to do with it!

see [JayData oData request with custom headers - ROUND 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689832/jaydata-odata-request-with-custom-headers-round-2)

the bellow "hack" works, but the above question should take this problem to a new level.

### ----------

### Old answer

Nevermind I found a solution.

It seems like `prepareRequest` is broken in JayData 1.3.2 (ODataProvider).

As a hack, I added an extraHeaders object in the providerConfiguration (oDataProvider.js):

```
  this.providerConfiguration = $data.typeSystem.extend({
                   //Leave content unchanged and add the following:
                    extraHeaders: {}
                }, cfg);
```

then at line 865 modify requestData like this:

```
var requestData = [
                    {
                        requestUri: this.providerConfiguration.oDataServiceHost + sql.queryText,
                        method: sql.method,
                        data: sql.postData,
                        headers: _.extend({
                            MaxDataServiceVersion: this.providerConfiguration.maxDataServiceVersion
                        },this.providerConfiguration.extraHeaders)
                    },
```

NOTE: Iam using lodash for conveniance, any js extend should do the trick.

then you just create your client like this:

```
 var entities = new Entities.MyEntities({
            name: 'oData',
            oDataServiceHost: 'http://myhost.com/DataService.svc',
            maxDataServiceVersion: "2.0",
            //enableJSONP: true,
            extraHeaders: {apikey:'f05d1c1e-b1b9-5a2d-2f44-da811bd50bd5', Accept:'application/json;odata=verbose'}
        }
    );
```

Comment: nice catch! I didn't know this bahavior of datajs

Comment: @Robesz Might be new in datajs 1.1.1. I saw a few posts where it worked for people to just override prepareRequest.

Comment: Actually this analysis is not correct. The normalizeHeaders function only normalizes the names of the headers listed in 'normalHeaders'. It ignores (doesn't modify or delete) all other headers.

Comment: thanks @Mark! You are right! `prepareRequest` is still broken though... But thats JayData's problem. dont' have the time to pin it down exactly. I edited my answer!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the marked answer is incorrect. I was suffering from a similar issue, but got it working without changing datajs.

My issue was that I was doing a cross domain (CORS) request, but didn't explicitly allow the headers. After I added the correct CORS header to the webservice, it worked.

Comment: Working here for datajs 1.1.1 and JayData 1.3.4/5 as well.

Comment: @RainerAtSpirit Ok for GET requests! but what about MERGE requests?

Comment: Good question. I'm talking to a .Net WebAPI OData v3 endpoint through a [hapijs](http://spumko.github.io/) based reverse proxy. OData v3 uses PATCH instead of MERGE, but I doubt that this makes a difference. If possible I'd try to avoid CORS in the first place and see if you can get it working that way.

Comment: @RainerAtSpirit I have to use V2, did you have look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689832/jaydata-odata-request-with-custom-headers-round-2 . there is definitelly something wrong and has nothing to do with CORS.